# datetime returns ' in the output

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

Relatively new to coding but I'm having an interesting issue it seems.

I've managed to get an output of the previous day (for use in a .loc comparison for a dataset) and it returns the date information in '20210513' , where the expected output is 20210513.

Is there a format that would help resolve this to just an int?

Code for reference:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    
d = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
date = d.strftime('%Y%m%d')
date
# This is the output that needs to be changed to int.
'20210513'
```

Comment: Not sure why you want this to be an int, but you can simply do `int(date)`.

Comment: ```int(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'))``` ?

Comment: That's not a date; it's  `str`, which you specifically requested by calling `d.strftime`.

Comment: Why would you need an int? Integers are closed under addition, and 20210513+40 is a valid integer, but no longer a valid date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fix this by using `int()`.

This is an example:

```
date = int(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
date
```

This should give you `20210513`

Comment: ```python
int(d.strftime('%Y%m%d')
``` 
should have an extra ) at the end to complete the int call, but yes, this does work! Thank you!